# I can’t divide these variables in ruby - how can I divide them?

Tags: ruby

Hey StackOverflow Community!

I am a content ruby user and am looking to find out a fix for a bug I have encountered in my marking program. I plan to convert it to rails later so my community can use it. The code is open source.

The problem is that it seems to be that I can’t output this code.
It returns the error “undefined method: /“ when I try to run the code. With no further ado, here is the code.

Yeah, I am entering it as a float btw.

```
Grade = gets.chomp
Outof = gets.chomp

Finalresult = grade/outof
```

This doesn’t print correctly and returns the “/“ method undefined error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
CassieCode

Comment: Sorry, but you have three mistakes: `gets`, and hence, `gets.chomp` always returns a string. You need `gets.chomp.to_f`, or simply `gets.to_f` (to convert to floats). #2 `Grade` and `Outof`, because they begin with capital letters, are constants. You want just variables. #3,  `grade` and `outof` are undefined local variables (`Grade` and `grade` are as different as night and day). If you could don't need `grade` and `outof` you could simply write `gets.to_f/gets.to_f`.

Comment: You might want to take a closer look at the _whole_ error message. It will tell you that the receiver is not a float, but a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gets.chomp` takes a user input and returns it as a string, it doesn't recognize what type you have assumed. You can't divide one string into another. The solution is to convert the input into floats. Also, all variable names should start from a downcase-letter.

See the difference

```
> outof = gets.chomp
0.5 # My input here
=> "0.5"
> outof.class
=> String
> outof = gets.chomp.to_f
0.5 # My input here
=> 0.5
> outof.class
=> Float
```

Here is the working code

```rb
grade = gets.to_f
outof = gets.to_f

finalresult = grade / outof
```

Comment: You can omit `chomp` when using `to_f`. Also have a look at the the global [`Float`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#Float-method) method which comes with some error handling.

Comment: @Stefan good point. I updated the answer.